# How to return cursor to method name after Ctrl + LEFT MOUSE on this method?

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have file with 1000 lines of source code. I'm looking through code and see call of private method and want to see the method, so I ctrl click it:
[image]

After clicking I see the implementation of the method:
[image]

After investigation I want to return my cursor to exact same place when it was before ctrl + click. But I lost the place in code.

If the method is used only once in the file than there are no problems with that(I'll just ctrl + click on method signature). But what if there are 20-30 usages of the private method? I don't want to remember line number each time.

Can this be achieved(return cursor)?

Comment: You mean like `CTRL`+`ALT`+`LEFT` (W10)?